# Display user selection on Data Grid View Button Column

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

My program currently contains a Data Grid View which links to a Popup window containing a Tree View. I have a function returning the user selection, and I would like to display this selection on the button.

Any ideas on how to do this? I can't find the property that allows me to do so.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

"A Data Grid View that links to a Popup window containing a Tree View" - when a cell (button) is clicked, a popup window shows up with a tree view in it. A string in the tree view is selected by a user in the tree view, and saved as a public property in the popup window. On closing, the string is retrieved from the popup window, and the Text of the button is set to the string.

This is my interpretation of the question.

Without knowing more precise information about the button, it's assumed the button is a member of a DataGridViewButtonColumn.

```
    void ClassForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        datagridview1.CellMouseDown -= MouseClick;
        datagridview1.CellMouseDown += MouseClick;
    }

    void MouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridView dgv = sender as DataGridView;
        if(dgv == null) return;

        DataGridViewButtonCell b = dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex] as DataGridViewButtonCell;
        if (b != null)
        {
            MyPopupTreeWindow myPopupTreeWindow = new MyPopupTreeWindow(optional information from button);
            myPopupTreeWindow.ShowDialog();
            string userSelectedString = myPopupTreeWindow.userSelectedString;
            datagridview1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value = userSelectedString;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can give you button Command Name then 
gridview rowcommand

```
<asp:GridView ID="DataGridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="DataGridView_RowCommand">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField NullDisplayText="N/A" />
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CommandName="yourCommandName">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>


 protected void DataGridView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {      
            if (e.CommandName == "yourCommandName")
              {
                //Do something here
              }
    }
```